# How can I solve Retrofit generic methods problem

Tags: java, gson, retrofit2

I wrote a method that will receive data from the API generically for the model classes that I will send using the Retrofit package. However, normally when doing it with a static model, data comes, but now no data is coming. Why?

When I use the `Call<T> call = (Call<T>) restInterfaceController.getData(responseType);` from the parameter responseType here, it gives an error `Expected 0 arguments but found 1`. Then, I create a create method with Intellisense and add the following code into the interface: `<T> Object getData(Class<T> responseType);` but it's not working. How can I solve this problem?

```
private <T> void RetrofitApply(Class<T> responseType) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.constants.baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestInterfaceController restInterfaceController = retrofit.create(RestInterfaceController.class);
    Call<T> call = (Call<T>) restInterfaceController.getData();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                T responseData = response.body();
                if (responseData != null) {
                    System.out.println("DATA : " + responseData);
                    System.out.println("ERROR CODE : " + response.code());
                    System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE: " + response.message());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Response data is null.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Response is not successful. : " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Interface here:

```
public interface RestInterfaceController {
    @GET("Europe/Istanbul")
    Call<Example> getData();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `Expected 0 arguments but found 1`. Then, I create a create method with Intellisense and add the following code into the interface: `<T> Object getData(Class<T> responseType);` but it's not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the details, **do not add pertinent information in comments**

Comment: Could you please explain how `RestInterfaceController.getData()` respectively the server you are sending the request to should behave? Your current `getData()` method takes no arguments, so the server should always return the same response format; in that case there should not be any need for a `responseType`. Could you please provide some examples for the response JSON data you receive, and why a `responseType` is necessary.